# 400 - Bad Request when using the pushalot api under python

Tags: python

I have the below code that I trying to send messages to a Windows Phone using the [Pushalot Api](https://pushalot.com/) as Pushalot haven't got any examples.

I know my api key works fine as the cURL method works fine, but my modified python script isn't working, keep getting -- 400, Bad Request and I'm not sure why.

Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from urllib import urlencode
from httplib import HTTPSConnection, HTTPException
from ssl import SSLError


pushalot_authorizationtoken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
pushalot_title = 'title'
pushalot_body = 'body'

http_handler = HTTPSConnection("pushalot.com")

data = {'AuthorizationToken': pushalot_authorizationtoken,
        'Title': pushalot_title.encode('utf-8'),
        'Body': pushalot_body.encode('utf-8') }

try:
    http_handler.request("POST",
                            "/api/sendmessage",
                            headers = {'Content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
                            body = urlencode(data))
except (SSLError, HTTPException):
    print("Pushalot notification failed.")            

response = http_handler.getresponse()

print(response.status, response.reason)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working today, weird, above code works.

Will leave this here for anyone else that needs the python code for pushalot api